# How to solve $\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{e^x\sin x}{x}dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, complex-numbers

> $z=x+iy$, solve $I=\int_0^1\frac{\sin(\ln(Re(z)))}{\ln(Re(z))}d(Re(z))$

$Re(z)=x$, so, I=$\int_0^1\frac{\sin(\ln x)}{\ln x}dx$. Put $\ln x=t$, so $\frac{dx}{x}=dt\implies dx=e^tdt$, so $I=\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{e^t\sin t}{t}dt$

Not able to proceed next.

Comment: Are you trying to compute an indefinite integral, i.e. find the antiderivative of $\frac{e^x\sin x}x$? Or is this a definite integral? Or maybe a complex contour integral?

Comment: @user170231 definite integral

Comment: Then please identify the integral which you seek to evaluate.

Comment: A more general result: $$\mathcal L (\operatorname{sinc})(s)=\operatorname{arccot}(s)$$ Use $s=1$ for your desired result.

Comment: Also see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4109949/interesting-integral-including-ln-x).

Comment: @NoName, that's a very beautiful solution. +1.

Comment: @aarbee Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define
$$F(a):= \int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\frac{\sin x}{x} dx$$
for $a > 0$. We require $F(1)$. Clearly, $F(a\to\infty) = 0$. Now, differentiation under the integral sign yields
$$F'(a) = -\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\sin x\:dx = \left.\frac{e^{-ax}(a\sin x + \cos x)}{1+a^2}\right|_{x=0}^\infty=-\frac{1}{1+a^2}.$$
Therefore,
$$F(a) = F(a) -F(\infty)= -\int_a^\infty F'(y)\:dy=\int_a^\infty\frac{dy}{1+y^2}=\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan a.$$
It follows that $F(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}.$

Comment: Thanks, how did you do the differentiation?

Comment: Well, $F'(a) = \int_0^\infty\partial_a\left(e^{-ax}\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)dx$. The partial derivative evaluates to $-xe^{-ax}\frac{\sin x}{x}$.

Comment: Thanks, how can we write F(a)=F(a)-F($\infty$)?

Comment: $F(\infty) = 0.$

Comment: Actually, with derivative, I was getting confused with Leibnitz rule but then realized that would be applicable if we were differentiating w.r.t. x.

Comment: I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Yes, it is clear now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Pur $u=-t$ to get $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin u}{u} e^{-u} du \\ = \int_0^{\infty} \sum_{0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{u^{2n}e^{-u}}{(2n+1)!} du \\ = \sum_0^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \int_0^{\infty} t^{2n} e^{-u} du$$ The integral is exactly $\Gamma (2n+1) =(2n)!$. Simplify to $$\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\tan^{-1} (1) =\frac{\pi}{4} $$

which follows from the series for $\arctan$.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not aware of the series you used. Is there any other simpler method to solve it?

Comment: @aarbee, the series used is just the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions) for $\sin(x)$

Comment: By writing (2n)!, what are we trying to convey? Also, what happened to the integral?

Comment: @aarbee The integral equals $(2n)!$. See the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Answer (score 1):

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^0\frac{sint}{t}e^{t}dt$$
Put u = -t

So, $$ I = \int_0^\infty \frac{sin u}{u}e^{-u}du$$
Note : $$\int_1^\infty e^{-ux}du = \frac{e^{-u}}{u}$$
And $$\int e^{ax}sin(bx) dx = \frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}(asin(bx)-bcos(bx))$$
So, $$ I = \int_0^\infty \int_1^\infty e^{-ux}sinu dx du$$
Changing the order of integration,
$$ I =\int_1^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-ux}sinu du dx$$
$$ I =\int_1^\infty [\frac{e^{-ux}}{x^2+1}(-xsinu-cosu)]_0^\infty dx$$
$$ I = \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$$
$$ I = [tan^{-1}x]_1^\infty$$
$$ I = \frac{π}{2}-\frac{π}{4}$$
$$ I = \frac{π}{4}$$
Hope this will help you!